# Range validation error is always showing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my Razor:

```
    <div class="row form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Number to answer</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.SelectedQuestions, new { style = "width: 10%", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.SelectedQuestions)
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the HTML generated:

```
<div class="row form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Number to answer</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedQuestions must be a number." data-val-range="The value entered must be bigger than zero." data-val-range-max="6" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The SelectedQuestions field is required." id="SelectedQuestions" name="SelectedQuestions" style="width: 10%" type="text" value="3">
                    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="SelectedQuestions" data-valmsg-replace="true">The value entered must be bigger than zero.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And that's how I have defined the property:

**CS Code**

```
[Range(1, 6, ErrorMessage = "The value entered must be bigger than zero.")]
    [Required]
    public int SelectedQuestions { get; set; }
```

That field does have valid data in it when my page LOADS, but it is still ALWAYS showing the red validation error under the field, **WHY?**

Also even if I delete the number in it and type something else, still it is red , it doesn't go away.

**If there are stuff I should add to `CSS` maybe? please let me know.**

Comment: Do you have the relevant files(js/css) loaded properly ?

Comment: @Shyju What relevant file? No I did not do anything with CSS

Comment: @Shyju : Please be more specific, if there is file , can you point me to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BundleConfig.cs file should have the following javascript files registered :

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

and the following css needs to be in your css (which I guess it is if you're seeing red) :

```
.field-validation-error {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

make sure your _layout.cshtml has thew following at the bottom :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

and then so long as you have the following either in your _layout or on your page all should work :

```
@{Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

Comment: Excellent , it worked. Thank you so much.  One FULL day I had spent on this.